# Updating an array of objects with setTimeout with react and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects, and each object has a false property value by default:

```
 const [items, setItems] =  useState([ { key: 1, has_x: false }, { key: 2, has_x: false }, { key: 3, has_x: false } ]);
```

Which is passed down to child components:

```
<Item key={item.key} hasX={item.has_x} />
```

In the parent component, I have a "Check All" button:

```
<button onClick={handleCheckAll}>Check All</button>
```

Which would loop through every item and modify `item.has_x` to true.

In the child components, there's also a "Check" button, but instead of checking all items, it just checks and sets that one specific item `has_x` to true.

I think I would know how to do each one. For the "Check All" function, I'd create a shadow copy, set the value, and then once the loop is done, set the state. For the child button, I really just need a useState there for it.

However, I am stuck on the "Check All" button because I'd like to have ui updates as `has_x` for each item gets updated and a setTimeout, as the actual functionality of check all will be expensive and needs about 200-300ms wait time for each check. Imagine a button's text changes to a checkmark as the function loops through each item.

Here's my attempt but the UI doesn't get updated and I only am setting the state once it's done:

```
const checkAllItems = () => {
    let temp = [...items];
    temp.map((item, index) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let tempEl = {...tempState[index]};
            if (tempEl) item.has_x = true;
        }, index * 200)
    })
    setItems(temp)
}
```

My only idea of how to do this is to use refs and loop through the refs to run a function in each child component that will do this, but I feel like there's a correct way to go about this. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine needing a timeout for updating state. I am certain if you tweak your check-all items code a bit you won't need the timeout. You can use a functional state update to enqueue the state updates and correctly update from the previous state instead of the state value closed over in callback scope.

```
const checkAllItems = () => {
  setItems(items => items.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    has_x: true,
  })));
};
```

This shallow copies the previous `items` state into a new array, and then you also shallow copy each `item` element and update the `has_x` property.

#### Update

If you are making backend API requests per checked update in `items` then I suggest doing this in a `useEffect` lifecycle hook. Loop over each `item` and enqueue the network request in a `setTimeout`. It's basically splitting out the timeout logic (*you had previously*) from the state update.

```
useEffect(() => {
  items.forEach((item, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // make API request with `item`
    }, index * 200);
  });
}, [items]);
```

/update

I also don't recommend the child components to ***also*** have any "checked" state, you want a single source of truth as to the checked status of your `items` array. Pass a callback to the children for them to update *their* checked status in the parent component's state.

It could look something like this:

```
const updateStatus = (key, value) => {
  setItems(items => items.map(item => item.key === key
    ? {
      ...item,
      has_x: value,
    }
    : item
  ));
};

...

<Item key={item.key} hasX={item.has_x} updateX={updateStatus} />
```

Comment: The reason for the setTimeout is because the actual checkAllItems will send a request to the server for each item and starts a ffmpeg process, so the setTimeout just helps gives the server some room to breath.

Comment: @kinx Ah, in this case then I suggest using a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on `items` to issue the side-effect of making the API requests.

Comment: it could be also better if the server could get the result for all the items at once, instead of one by one

Comment: @kinx I agree with zb22, you could enqueue the update, check all the `has_x` properties, then use an `useEffect` hook to make a single bulk request to your backend, and let your server divvy up its workload.

Comment: I could do that, but how my server is already built is with a single request per item. This way, I can get visual feedback for each one and also, if ffmpeg decides to "crash" and the next fetch doesn';t get a response, the "check" stops and i can continue after iit's all OK again vs sending all of the data to the server, and hoping it'll work out without any per-item visual feedback.

So, your code works great and it does check each item it seems, however is there anyway to get the setTimeout working inside of th setItems block of code?

Comment: That way, I can: Send a fetch, the server usually sends a success: true, if so, has_x is set to true, if not and there's a timeout, i can exit out of it and re-check again.

Comment: @kinx Oh, I see, so the new item values depend on the response from each request?

Comment: Correct, because ffmpeg is heavy, i don't want to just send everything to the server. While i can do that, I would really prefer to have that visual feedback per item.

Comment: This makes sense, I just don't understand how useEffect is triggered in this situation after checkAll is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort!! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Also how is the state updated?

Comment: Well, it'd be triggered by the state being updated. I'll think about this to see if I come up with a better solution closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: I actually been doing this as an alternative in console until i can figure it out lol

`
[...$$('.results .item button:not(.checked)')].slice(0, 100).forEach((b, i) => {
    setTimeout(() => { b.click() }, i * 1200)
});
`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/delayed-loading-9zo8v?file=/src/App.js:233-259

thanks for your help!